# 0x4 Decompression error in Python Confluent Kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, compression, confluent-kafka-python

I've been having trouble getting python-confluent-kafka to work on my windows server.

When creating a simple consumer on my local machine, everything works fine.
However, once on the windows server, I will receive the messages but get the following error:

> b'Decompression (codec 0x4) of message at 24023756 of 9550 bytes failed: Local: Not implemented'

I copied the exact conda environment I have on my local machine to the server.

Comment: I'm not sure what codec that is, but on Linux at least, I've had to separately install snappy or zstd C libraries into the OS

Comment: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/2951

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it had to do with the .dll's not being found due to the Path/Environment Variables not being configured properly.